# How to send a scheduler job created in a package?

Tags: oracle, plsql, scheduler, jobs

I have developed an application to launch jobs according to a process order from an oracle plsql program and it has been working fine.

The main program reads a table where the programs to be executed are registered and sends them with a job;

> ```
> cJob := 'begin  
> pkg_procesos_carga.ejecutar(''' ||
> aProcesosCarga(nProcesoActual).esquema || ''',''' ||
> aProcesosCarga(nProcesoActual).proceso || '''); 
> end;';
>
> dbms_job.submit(job => nJob,
> what => cJob);
> COMMIT;`
> ```

That worked fine.

I have been asked to change the jobs to scheduler and I have developed a similar process:

> ```
> cJob := 'BEGIN' || kNL;
> cJob := cJob || 'DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(' || kNL;
> cJob := cJob || ' job_name => ' || '' || cJobProcess || '' || ',' || kNL;
> cJob := cJob || ' job_type => ' || '''STORED_PROCEDURE''' || ',' || kNL;
> cJob := cJob || ' job_action => ' || '' || cAction || '' || ',' || kNL;
> cJob := cJob || ' auto_drop => TRUE,' || kNL;
> cJob := cJob || 'enabled => TRUE,' || kNL;
> ```

That code may have some errors but that is the idea.

Is there any way to launch the scheduler job from a package?

Thank you.

Comment: Of course there is... just use dbms_scheduler.create_job. But there is no reason to use dynamic SQL... just make a normal procedure call without all that string work.

Comment: I wanted to create schedulers job dinamically, and run it from a procedure.

Comment: The only time you need dynamic SQL within Oracle stored procedures is when you are abtracting dictionary object names in SQL, compiling structural DDL, or generating dynamic PL/SQL code. For creating jobs, you simply make a normal procedure call, passing in the parameters desired using variables. There is no need to make that dynamic... by nature it already is.

Comment: Job is not launched by PL/SQL code. The scheduler runs the job as long as it is enabled, its `start_date` has passed or `event_condition` is satisfied, its schedule window is active and scheduler has enough slots to start a new task. All these are true for your sample code (except resource allocation, which we may not know of).

Comment: Looks like your task is just to change `dbms_job.submit()` to `dbms_scheduler.create_job()`, passing suitable parameters to make it a one-time background job that starts immediately, and leave the rest alone.